# How do you separate adjacent code blocks?

Tags: support, code-formatting, markdown

I was just looking at this question: [changing the innertext of a nested node and assigning it the value of the first sibling of the parent node in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643060/changing-the-innertext-of-a-nested-node-and-assigning-it-the-value-of-the-first).

The original poster has put an XML code block followed by a C# code block. Stack Overflow's markdown interpreter has decided that these should both be the same code block with a single scroll bar. Is it possible to separate these into two code blocks with separate scroll bars, without putting any text in between?

Comment: Some hidden html tags: `<br>`, `<!-- -->` will do the trick